# Binding to properties does not update the related property

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, xaml, binding

I have on the server side class `Person` with some properties, one of them is `PhoneNumber` (this is `edmx` auto generated - from DB). In the `UI` I have 2 `textboxes`, one is `prefix`, and the other is `postfix`, so I wanted to extend `Person` class and make it partial with 2 more properties, `prefix` and `postfix` and in the UI bind them to this properties which will update the `PhoneNumber` property, but somehow, prefix and postfix has value but `PhoneNumber` does not.

Here is my code:

**Server Side:**

```
Public partial class Person : EntityObject
{
    //Auto generated from edmx
    ...
    ...
    /// <summary>
    /// No Metadata Documentation available.
    /// </summary>
    [EdmScalarPropertyAttribute(EntityKeyProperty=false, IsNullable=true)]
    [DataMemberAttribute()]
    public global::System.String PhoneNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return _PhoneNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            OnPhoneNumberChanging(value);
            ReportPropertyChanging("PhoneNumber");
            _PhoneNumber = StructuralObject.SetValidValue(value, true, "PhoneNumber");
            ReportPropertyChanged("PhoneNumber");
            OnPhoneNumberChanged();
        }
    }
}

public partial class Person
{
    [DataMember]
    public string PhoneNumberPrefix
    {
        get { return PhoneNumber.Substring(0, 3); }
        set { PhoneNumber = value + PhoneNumber.Substring(3); }
    }

    [DataMember]
    public string PhoneNumberPostfix
    {
        get { return PhoneNumber.Substring(3); }
        set { PhoneNumber = PhoneNumber.Substring(0, 3) + value; }
    }
}
```

**Client Side:**

`DataContext` is the `Person`.

```
<TextBox Grid.Column="0" MaxLength="3"
                         Text="{Binding PhoneNumberPrefix, Mode=TwoWay}" />
<TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="-" />
<TextBox Grid.Column="2"
         Text="{Binding PhoneNumberPostfix, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

[image]

**Final Result:**

After I add values to those `textboxes` I get the values in `Prefix` and `Postfix` but the `PhoneNumber` is still `null`. Print screen in debug mode:

[image]

I have tried to add `UpdateSourceTrigger` or Implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and no help, can someone help me please?

Thanks in advance !

Comment: What do you mean by `PhoneNumber` is null and `Prefix`, `PostFix` got values? If `PhoneNumber` is null, postFix and prefix will crash with null reference exception since they are substrings only of property PhoneNumber.

Comment: @RohitVats I have added an image answering to your question. This does not crash also, maybe the setter and getter does not work?

Comment: @Rohit Binding sort of catches exceptions and if you set the property validate on exception the Binding will validate the TextBox on exception in setter. The exeception is never literally thrown out of scrope

Comment: @Misha What is this part of code doing: _PhoneNumber = StructuralObject.SetValidValue? Maybe you return null there.

Comment: @devhedgehog This is auto generated by Entity-Framework, I just copied it.

Comment: @MishaZaslavsky Do you set null there?

Comment: @devhedgehog What do you mean? I don't set null, it is null by default.

Comment: Ahhh now I understand you. Because its null the exeception is being thrown before you set the value but Binding catches the exception and so your application doesnt crash. Try out my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of PhoneNumber.Substring(0, 3) try this:

```
PhoneNumber != null ? PhoneNumber.Substring(0, 3) : string.Empty;
```

Or ask manually if(PhoneNumber != null)...